# QGIS Composer not rendering HTML

Tags: qgis, print-composer, linux, arch-linux

The title. When I select the "Render as HTML" option on a text box on the Layout Composer, the text disapears.

[image: Without the option selected]

[image: With the option selected]

I only found a QGIS bug report from some years ago, mentioning that it might be a dependency issue, related to Qt webkit, but I have it installed on the system (`qt5-webkit`). On the Arch Package website for QGIS, there is no dependency related to `qt5-webkit` directly.

Not sure is this is a proper bug that I can file on the QGIS bug tracker, or if this is an issue related to the Arch package itself (https://archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/qgis/).

*Even though I'm using EndeavourOS, all the packages are directly from the Arch repositories, so this is not an issue related to EOS itself. EOS repositories only supply some packages related to the customization and visual aspect of the system.*

EDIT: The issue finally solved itself. I can't pinpoint the solution, but I'm sure it's related to some dependency.